# ckeditor underline not allowed on filtered HTML

Tags: wysiwyg

I have a problem whereby I cant underline text using ckeditor whilst in Filter HTML, it works fine with Full HTML. I can also use Bold and Italic with Filter HTML but not Underline. Is there a configuration setting for this, so a User set up with just permission for Filter HTML can add underline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to allow `<u>` HTML tags in 'Filtered HTML' filter (/admin/config/content/formats/filtered_html).

Comment: many thanks, I've put up with this problem for ages :)